# Generating Fibonacci Numbers Using variable-Length Arrays Code Compiler Error

Tags: c, arrays, fibonacci

Compile error in vs2010(Win32 Console Application Template) for the code below. How can I fix it.

```
unsigned long long int Fibonacci[numFibs]; // error occurred here
```

error C2057: expected constant expression

error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

error C2133: 'Fibonacci' : unknown size

**Complete code attached**(It's a sample code from programming In c -3E book. No any modify)

```
int main()
{

 int i, numFibs;

 printf("How may Fibonacci numbers do you want (between 1 to 75)? ");
 scanf("%i", &numFibs);

 if ( numFibs < 1 || numFibs > 75){
  printf("Bad number, sorry!\n");
  return 1;
 }

 unsigned long long int Fibonacci[numFibs];

 Fibonacci[0] = 0; // by definition
 Fibonacci[1] = 1; // ditto

 for ( i = 2; i < numFibs; ++i)
  Fibonacci[i] = Fibonacci[i-2] + Fibonacci[i-1];

 for ( i = 0; i < numFibs; ++i)
  printf("%11u",Fibonacci[i]);

 printf("\n");

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Before you get too far in that book I recommend you browsing around to find all the differences between C89 and C99. Your book looks to be using C99. C89 is the most common "standard C" out there. C99 changes a few things, probably for the worst, but you're better off knowing what the differences are and know how to spot different standards.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe, Yeah, I found the information about ANSI C99 used upon my book book from it's Introduction chapter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which compiler are you using? And are you compiling as C or C++? 
Variable-length arrays are legal in C since [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), but if you're using an older compiler (or compiling as C++) they won't work.

As a workaround, you can switch to using dynamic allocation:

```
typedef unsigned long long uint64; // just for convenience
uint64* Fibonacci = (uint64*)malloc(sizeof(uint64)*numFibs);
// {code here}
// then at the end:    
free(Fibonacci);
return 0;
```

Comment: VS2010. I created a win32 console application for practicing the code. I guess I compiled it as C++ application.

Comment: Yeah, VS isn't the really best option for C programming. You can try getting minGW/msys to use gcc..

Comment: @Nano HE : Thanks! Note that while the answer you accepted is fine, using a `#define` means you won't be able to select how many numbers to generate at run-time.

Comment: @tzaman, I keep on study your code and I pasted to http://codepad.org/XuoHCP5T , It doesn't work. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @Nano - you need to replace the original Fibonacci declaration with the one I provided. Also, `scanf` won't work on codepad, I think. Here: http://codepad.org/IsECBa4A

Answer (score 2):

VS2010 is a C++ compiler by default, and C++ does not support variable length arrays. You can change your project to compile code as C code, but VS2010 still doesn't really support C99.

I would recommend you use `gcc` for C code, it's much more conformant.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an array of variable length. Use dynamic allocation returning pointer (malloc)

Comment: This is actually incorrect; C99 does support variable length arrays.

Comment: Well, it's both. The questioner didn't specify which standard. When people talk about standard C, we're usually talking about the good C 89, unless otherwise specified. Although, maybe you could argue it was implied because the OP used the C++ style comments. My advice, stick with C89 and prefer malloc for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Either dynamically allocate the array or use a constant array size.

```
#define kMaxFibs 75
...
if ( numFibs < 1 || numFibs > kMaxFibs){
...
unsigned long long int Fibonacci[kMaxFibs];
```

Comment: @drawnonward, I'd like to use vs2010 for my dev ide. After followed your suggestion, it works quite well now.

@All, Thank you.